# Mesh analysis to find Vx

Tags: analysis, mesh-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw0jlp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to solve the following circuit using mesh analysis. Here is my equation. The goal is to find the value for Vx. **Vx is the also the parameter over R3

Loop1

```
i1=1mA  ----------------------Eq1
```

Loop2

```
2k(i2-1mA)+3+1k(i2)=0
i2=-1/3000A   ----------------Eq2
```

Loop3

```
1k(i3-1mA)+2vx-3=0
1ki3=Vx-3    -----------------Eq3
```

Loop2 again

```
1ki2-Vx+3=0 ------------------Eq4
```

Sub(Eq2)into(Eq4)

```
Vx=7/3V
```

Comment: Duplicate question on mesh analysis

Comment: Loop1 is incorrect. You can't apply the loop rule on currents.